# Second Order Linear Differential Equation $(t+3)^2y'' + (6t+18)y'+6y = e^t$ for $t > -3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question States:

"Find the general solution to the following equation
$$(t+3)^2y'' + (6t+18)y'+6y = e^t$$ for $t > -3$.

I am not sure how to proceed. First we can try to find 2 linearly independent solutions to the homogeneous equation, and use variation of parameters to find a particular solution and add all three up. How would I be able to solve the 2 equations for the homogeneous equation? I tried setting $y$ equal to a second degree polynomial but failed; similarly for setting $y$ equal to $e^{\lambda t}$.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe No, nothing so simple.  These are not constant coefficients.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry!                                                                                      EDIT : Removed incorrect comment.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you've copied the question correctly?

According to Maple, the general solution to the homogeneous DE is

$$ y \left( t \right) ={\frac {c_{{1}}{{\rm e}^{ 1/\left( t+3 \right) 
}} \left( 2\,t+7 \right) }{ \left( t+3 \right) ^{4}}}+{\frac {c_{{2}}
 \left(  \left( -2\,t-7 \right) {{\rm e}^{ 1/\left( t+3 \right)}}{
\it Ei} \left( 1, \left( t+3 \right) ^{-1} \right) +{t}^{2}+7\,t+12
 \right) }{ \left( t+3 \right) ^{4}}}
$$

where $Ei$ is an exponential integral function.  In particular, it is not elementary.  You can then get a particular solution using variation of parameters, but it won't be pretty.

Comment: Oops, sorry! It should be 6t+18, not 6t+19.

Answer (score 0):

Using $x=\ln(t+3)$ for $t+3>0$ we find $(t+3)y'=\dfrac{dy}{dx}=Y'$ and $(t+3)^2y''=\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\dfrac{dy}{dx}=Y''-Y'$ after simplification you get
$$Y''+5Y'+6Y=0$$
that concludes general solution $Y=C_1e^{-2x}+C_2e^{-3x}$ or 
$$y=\frac{C_1}{(t+3)^2}+\frac{C_2}{(t+3)^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

The equation can be written as $$(t+3)^2y''+6(t+3)y'+6y=e^t$$
Let's suppose that $y=(t+3)^k$ is a solution of the homogeneous DE
$$(t+3)^2y''+6(t+3)y'+6y=0\tag{1}$$
i.e. 
\begin{align*}
 &&k(k-1)(t+3)^k+6k(t+3)^k+6(t+3)^k&=0\quad\text{for all }t>-3\\
\iff&&(k^2+5k+6)(t+3)^k&=0\quad\text{for all }t>-3\\
\iff&&k&\in\{-2,-3\}
\end{align*}

Then, $y_c=c_1(t+3)^{-2}+c_2(t+3)^{-3},\;\;t>-3\;$ is a solution of the homogeneous $(1)$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants. Now proceed for variation of parameters: look for two functions $u_1=u_1(t)$ and $u_2=u_2(t)$ such that
$$(t+3)^{-2}u_1'+(t+3)^{-3}u_2'=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad -2(t+3)^{-3}u_1'-3(t+3)^{-4}u_2'=e^t(t+3)^{-2}$$
Hence
$$u_1'=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}0&(t+3)^{-3}\\e^t(t+3)^{-2}&-3(t+3)^{-4}\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}(t+3)^{-2}&(t+3)^{-3}\\-2(t+3)^{-3}&-3(t+3)^{-4}\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{-e^t(t+3)^{-5}}{-(t+3)^{-6}}=(t+3)e^t\quad\implies\quad u_1=(t+2)e^t$$
$$u_2'=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}(t+3)^{-2}&0\\-2(t+3)^{-3}&e^t(t+3)^{-2}\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}(t+3)^{-2}&(t+3)^{-3}\\-2(t+3)^{-3}&-3(t+3)^{-4}\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{e^t(t+3)^{-4}}{-(t+3)^{-6}}=-(t+3)^2e^t\implies u_2=-(t^2+4t+5)e^t$$
Then, the solution is
$$y=c_1(t+3)^{-2}+c_2(t+3)^{-3}+(t+2)(t+3)^{-2}e^t-(t^2+4t+5)(t+3)^{-3}e^t$$
which simplifies to
$$\boxed{y=c_1(t+3)^{-2}+c_2(t+3)^{-3}+(t+1)(t+3)^{-3}e^t}$$